# Kibud av - kibud rav

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

The Rambam says in hilchos Talmud Torah (5:1) that the kavod one must have for his rebbe takes priority over the kavod he must have for his father.

> כשם שאדם מצווה בכבוד אביו ויראתו כך הוא חייב בכבוד רבו ויראתו יתר
> מאביו. שאביו מביאו לחיי העולם הזה ורבו שלמדו חכמה מביאו לחיי העולם
> הבא. ראה אבידת אביו ואבידת רבו של רבו קודמת לשל אביו. אביו ורבו נושאים
> במשא מניח את של רבו ואחר כך של אביו. אביו ורבו שבויים בשביה פודה את
> רבו ואחר כך פודה את אביו. ואם היה אביו תלמיד חכם פודה את אביו תחלה.
> וכן אם היה אביו תלמיד חכם אע"פ שאינו שקול כנגד רבו משיב אבידתו ואחר כך
> משיב אבידת רבו. ואין לך כבוד גדול מכבוד הרב ולא מורא ממורא הרב. אמרו
> חכמים מורא רבך כמורא שמים. לפיכך אמרו כל החולק על רבו כחולק על השכינה
> שנאמר בהצותם על ה'. וכל העושה מריבה עם רבו כעושה מריבה עם השכינה שנאמר
> אשר רבו בני ישראל את ה' ויקדש בם. וכל המתרעם על רבו כמתרעם על ה' שנאמר
> לא עלינו תלונותיכם כי על ה'. וכל המהרהר אחר רבו כאילו מהרהר אחר שכינה
> שנאמר וידבר העם באלהים ובמשה:

In hilchos Mamrim (6:4) he says that a father who is a talmid of his own son need not stand up for him, and the son, who is the rebbe, must stand up for the father.

> והאב שהיה תלמיד בנו אין האב עומד מפני הבן אבל הבן עומד מפני אביו אף על
> פי שהוא תלמידו וחייב לכבדו בשאר דרכיו בשעת עשיית משאו ומתנו ועשיית
> חפציו

What's pshat??!!

Comment: *Kavod rebbo* is a *hiddur* in *kavod aviv*.